# Python: Request URL via POST and show result in browser

Tags: python, http, urllib2, python-webbrowser

I'm a developer for a big GUI app and we have a web site for bug tracking. Anybody can submit a new bug to the bug tracking site. We can detect certain failures from our desktop app (i.e. an unhandled exception) and in such cases we would like to open the submit-new-bug form in the user predefined browser, **adding whatever information we can gather about the failure to some form fields**. We can either retrieve the submit-new-bug form using GET or POST http methods and we can provide default field values to that form. So from the http server side everything is pretty much OK.

So far we can successfully open a URL passing the default values as GET parameters in the URL using [the `webbrowser` module](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) from the Python Standard Library. There are, however, some [limitations of this method](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html#exc) such as the maximum allowed length of the URL for some browsers ([specially MS IE](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q208427)). The `webbrowser` module doesn't seem to have a way to request the URL using POST. OTOH there's [the `urllib2` module](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) that provides the type of control we want but AFAIK it lacks the possibility of opening the retrieved page in the user preferred browser.

**Is there a way to get this mixed behavior we want (to have the fine control of [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) with the higher level functionallity of [`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html))?**

PS: We have thought about the possibility of retreiving the URL with [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), saving its content to a temp file and opening that file with [`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html). This is a little nasty solution and in this case we would have to deal with other issues such as relative URLs. Is there a better solution?

Comment: if we have an html file , is there any possibility to create a website using python and display the html data?

Answer (score 9):

**This is not proper answer. but it also work**

```
import requests
import webbrowser

url = "https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=110"
myInput = {'email':'mymail@gmail.com','pass':'mypaass'}
x = requests.post(url, data = myInput)
y = x.text
f = open("home.html", "a")
f.write(y)
f.close()
webbrowser.open('file:///root/python/home.html')
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any way you can open the result of a POST request in a web browser without saving the result to a file and opening that.

What about taking an alternative approach and temporarily storing the data on the server. Then the page can be opened in the browser with a simple id parameter, and the saved partially filled form would be shown.

Comment: That looks promising but unfortunately we can't change server side code. At least not without a very strong reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

```
import tempfile
import webbrowser
import jinja2

t = jinja2.Template('hello {{ name }}!') # you could load template from a file
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() # deleted when goes out of scope (closed)
f.write(t.render(name='abc'))
f.flush()
webbrowser.open_new_tab(f.name) # returns immediately
```

A better approach if the server can be easily modified is to make `POST` request with partial parameters using `urllib2` and open url generated by server using `webbrowser` as [suggested by @Acorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8637506/4279).

Comment: The command "webbrowser.open_new_tab(f.name)" will not work in Mac OS. You will have to include the protocol too: webbrowser.open_new_tab('file://' + f.name)

Comment: You may also want to change tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() for tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

Comment: @PauloCheque: [`webbrowser` adds `file:` to local urls by itself](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/webbrowser.py#l585)

Comment: @PauloCheque: `delete=True` enables automatic cleanup. Notice: that I use `f.flush()` (make data available to the OS) instead of `f.close()` (close and delete the file).

Answer (score 0):

If using `selenium`, instead of writing to a file, it is possible to inject a script to write the HTML page generated from the response:

```py
response = requests.post('https://xxx', data = ...)
response_html = response.text 
driver.get("about:blank")
driver.execute_script("document.write(arguments[0])", response_html)
```